# Деепричастие "начиная с"

Tags: запятые, деепричастия

Деепричастие "начиная с", которое употреблено в  контексте времени, обособляется, если имеет характер уточнения или пояснения.

Среди прочих, в примерах Розенталя есть следующий пример, когда оборот с "начиная с" нужно обособить:

Призы лучшим спортсменам континентов присуждаются, начиная с конца XIX века, в Лос-Анджелесе.

Разве в данном случае оборот имеет характер уточнения или пояснения? Или он обособляется по другой причине?

Answer (score 1):

***Призы лучшим спортсменам континентов присуждаются, начиная с конца XIX века, в Лос-Анджелесе.***

**Розенталь:** Но если оборот со словами ***начиная с*** носит характер уточнения, **попутного пояснения** или не связан с понятием времени (слово ***начиная*** нельзя опустить без ущерба для смысла предложения), то он обособляется.

Здесь обособленный оборот имеет **значение попутного пояснения**.

Это значение **задает автор текста, когда выбирает структуру** предложения. Здесь два неоднородных обстоятельства, уточнять друг друга они не могут.

Если автор считал бы их **равнозначными** по смыслу, то он составил бы такое предложение: ***Начиная с конца XIX века призы лучшим спортсменам континентов присуждаются в Лос-Анджелесе.***

Но, видимо, информацию о времени автор счел дополнительной, важно было указать именно место. Поэтому он ставит оба обстоятельства **в конец предложения,** а в этом случае их **сложно прочитать в одну фразу без обособления.** Поэтому обособленное обстоятельство приобретает характер  попутного объяснения.